# possibility of creating a new env using conda and install packages with pip

Tags: python, pip, conda

I need various python versions for different projects. May I create different environments using conda with different python versions and install the required packages for each project using pip?

Will this not cause any incompatibility?
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

No, there are no incompatibilities.

If you create each of these setups in their own environment, you should be fine.

Just make sure you have activated the correct Conda environment when using Pip to install extra packages.

(If you can install the same package(s) through Conda, that may be preferred. Just don't install a package through Conda and Pip, e.g. when trying to upgrade a package.)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is No. I will not cause any incompatibilities.
You can create different conda environments with the required python version and install the packages with different version as per your projects requirements. This will not cause any incompatibilities to your existing projects since conda environments are isolated from other environments on your system.

It is specifically used for isolating the project dependencies, so that one dependency with x version should not cause any issue for the project that requires same dependency with y version.

You can create conda environment using this command:
`conda create --name myenv python=3.9`

Replace the `3.9` with the python version you want to use.

Note:
Just make sure to activate your environment before you install the packages, otherwise packages will be install globally and that will cause issues.
`conda activate myenv`

Comment: Maybe, I was not clear enough. Suppose I installed a new env using the following command  conda create name env python=3.8. In the following, I need to install packages such as tqdm, CV2, numpy, panda etc. Is this procedure ok or we should do the 2nd step (numpy instalttion) only using conda?

Comment: You can install pip in your conda environment and start installing packages using pip. That is perfectly fine. If you do `conda list`, conda will tag the packages installed using pip differently to indicate that those are installed with pip. I would suggest to be consistent with the package manager you use. Either use pip or conda to install packages. Using both might cause some issue that I'm not aware of.